# Removing a character from a string and make them different values. PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a string

```
$emails = "[email1@domain.com][email2@gmail.com][email3@example.com]";
```

I want to print the emails as options in a html FORM for that is:

```
    <select>
    <option value="email1@domain.com">
    <option value="email2@gmail.com">
    <option value="email3@example.com">
    </select>
```

Please show me how.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+split+brackets+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: `preg_match_all('/\[.*?\]/')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare string to remove brackets.

```
$emails_prepared = str_replace(']', '', str_replace('[', '', str_replace('][', ' ', $emails)));
```

Then just split the prepared string into an array

```
$emails_array = explode(' ', $emails_prepared);
```

And finally, you just need to use the array of emails in a view

```
<select>
<?php
foreach ($emails_array as $email): ?>
    <option value="<?php $email ?>">
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Basically, it should be enough.